# Unable to install, update, or upgrade any packages on ubuntu 20.04 aws ec2 instance

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install net-tools using

```
sudo apt install net-tools
```

but I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package net-tools
```

So I tried the following commands

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt upgrade 
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt -f install
sudo apt autoremove
```

each of them respond with

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

any suggestions to fix this issue without breaking the server would be appreciated!

Comment: The `net-tools` package has been deprecated for quite some time (I think about 8 years now). Are you installing it to use `ifconfig`?

Comment: I wanted to use netstat

Comment: Hmm … seems that [the package is still available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/net-tools) for 20.04. Unless you’re using a less common platform, I don’t see why you can’t install it. Perhaps `ss -ltu` will give you what you need?

Comment: that worked! thank you